# Remove only first instance of duplicate values from two ArrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two lists that might look like this:

```
A: {1 3 1 2}
B: {1 3}
```

I would like to remove the elements of list `B` from list `A` and end up with:

```
A: {1 2}
```

But if I use `A.removeAll(B)` I will end up with only the value **2** since all the duplicate instances of value **1** will be removed from list `A`. My solution up until now was to use an Iterator over all elements of `A` and then all elements of `B` and if I find a similar value then remove it from both lists until list `B` is empty.

Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: What would be the result for `B: {3 1}`?

Comment: @BheshGurung Exactly the same, the order of the elements should not be important

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use a nested loop.
Loop on the `b` that contains the value to remove in `a`  and 
use `List.remove(Object)` instead of `List.removeAll(Collection)`.
It will remove the first element equals to the parameter and not all of them.

```
List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 3, 1, 2));
List<Integer> b = Arrays.asList(1, 3);

for (Integer currentInt : b) {
    a.remove(currentInt);
}

System.out.println(a);
```

Output :

> [1, 2]